# Why does read add newline with default IFS and a single variable?

Tags: linux, bash

I was experimenting with `IFS` and `read`. I tried the following and I can't get my head around why it resulted this way:

```
$ IFS=$' \t\n'
$ read a <<< "the plain gold ring"
$ printf "=%s=\n" $a
=the=
=plain=
=gold=
=ring=
```

1. Is `a` an array now? Or is it a string?
2. Why did `read` add newline between two words?
3. Why is `printf` printing as if it is inside a loop?

I actually expected no separation would occur because I am reading into a single variable `a` only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. Is `a` an array now? Or is it a string?

It's a string. You told `read` to read to a single variable, the entire string was stored as `a`. If the command was `read a b c <<< …`, then `a` would get `the`, `b` would get `plain` and `c` would get `gold ring`.

> 2. Why did `read` add newline between two words?

It didn't, `printf` did because you told it to. Run `echo $a`.

> 3. Why is `printf` printing as if it is inside a loop?

Because `$a` expands to multiple words. The format you provided expects one string, it gets many. With too many arguments `printf` loops. Compare `printf "=%s=\n" "$a"` where `"$a"` is a single argument to `printf`.

Comment: Your answer to question 1 says it is a string (which I read as: single string value). But your answer to question 3 says multiple words (which I read as: multiple string values i.e., array of strings).
Could you elaborate please?

Comment: @joker It's about how the shell parses commands. Read [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/78924/108618) please. The point is `$a` undergoes word splitting, `"$a"` doesn't. This has nothing to do with arrays.

Comment: @joker Disclaimer: this has nothing to do with arrays in Bash. There are other contexts, e.g. we can say there is an array of arguments of `printf`, `$a` is split and gives four consecutive elements of this array, `"$a"` gives just one. Any string is an array of characters and this is yet another context. Even in Bash in your case there is in fact a formal array `"${a[@]}"` with just one element `"${a[0]}"` which is the same as `"$a"`. Every normal variable may be treated as a sole element of an array with the same name (try `echo "${PATH[0]}"`). In this context every variable is an array.